# Configure Zenoss login screen for SSL URL

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, zenoss

I'm trying to configure Zenoss 4.2.X to use an SSL-enabled URL in the login form.

I have nginx as an SSL reverse-proxy sending requests to Zenoss listening on port 8080. This works.

However, the **login form** uses "http://10.1.2.3:8080/zport/acl_users/cookieAuthHelper/login" as the POST action. This is a non-starter!

I need to configure Zenoss to use a different URL in the login form's POST action field. I've searched the internet and Zenoss docs to no avail. The closest answers I've found do not show this problem.

I've tried the following:

- Set `<cgi-environment>` in ZENHOME/etc/zope.conf as follows:

  ```
  <cgi-environment>
      HTTPS ON
      HTTPS_PORT 443
  </cgi-environment>
  ```

  But this causes a 302 redirect to `https://10.1.2.3/....` which is not correct. SSL is only on the nginx proxy.
- I tried setting `server_name` to the fqdn in nginx, but the URL in the login form is still the `http://10.1.2.3/...` value

Basically I'm just looking for a way for the backend SSL reverse-proxy to stay intact, but the UI, only, get rewrites to change the "app URL" to be the https:// version.

In many LAMP apps, there's a configuration directive to set the app URL. (e.g. Moodle, Drupal, Worpress). Does Zope have something similar?

Comment: Why the down vote? SO is super frustrating anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything what do you need to setup - it's your case nginx as reverse proxy for zope: http://wiki.zenoss.org/Newsletter:5/Encrypt_All_the_Bits

Comment: I have no idea why this got downvoted -- I didn't do it. I finally found a solution, and it is this link that you posted. I really wish people would state why they down vote. FWIW I upvoted you back to zero.